# SELECT X WHERE X has used Y >1

Tags: sql

Can I do a count to find orders which have used a discount code more than once?

```
Order       Codes
123         mowerwo
151         femorfm
151         geirmgr
151         rtert
161         erger
161         wefww
162         wweff
```

So I want it to bring back orders: 151 & 161

```
SELECT COUNT (discountcode) AS discount, order_num
FROM ordersdiscount 
HAVING COUNT (discountcode)>1
```

Comment: you are just missing a `GROUP BY order_num` before the `HAVING`

Comment: My days -.- Cheers for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
SELECT order_num
FROM orderdiscount
GROUP BY discountcode
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```

if you need only the code don't do unnecessary count

Comment: the `count (*)` is calculated anyway, since you are using it in the `HAVING`

Comment: the count(*) in the select statement count the number of returned rows, count(*) in having count, count relative to the group by statament and he only wants to count the number of rows for each group @Lamak

Comment: No, you are confused, is the same `COUNT(*)` value

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all columns in the `select` and `group by` *lists*( here `order_num` ) which is not an aggregate function such as *sum, count, avg* etc.

`count(*)` or `count(1)` or `count(0)` or `count(order_num)` all give the same result.

So use :

```
SELECT order_num, count(1) as discount
  FROM ordersdiscount 
 GROUP BY order_num
HAVING count(1)>1;

order_num   discount
   151         3
   161         2
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d6fc2/1)

Comment: `count(discountcode)` won't give the same results if the column has `NULL` values, though

Comment: @Lamak yes, need to say `count(order_num)` instead, ok, thanks.